# Writing to a text file from SQL Server with out using Command shell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a log file when ever a script is run. the Log file is .txt file. I am using the following codeto do that -

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[WriteToFile]

    @File        VARCHAR(2000),
    @Text        VARCHAR(2000)

    AS 

    BEGIN 

    DECLARE @OLE            INT 
    DECLARE @FileID         INT 


    EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @OLE OUT 

    EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE, 'OpenTextFile', @FileID OUT, @File, 8, 1 

    EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @FileID, 'WriteLine', Null, @Text

    EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @FileID 
    EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE 

    END
```

I have already activated the permissions for them to work but they are not working. Figured out that the "   EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @OLE OUT" did not create the log file and then I tried to create a file and write to it even that did not work.

I am exec it with the following command

```
EXEC WriteToFile 'C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\log1.txt','Did it work?'
```

Can any one help me figure this out?

Comment: I tried your code and my file was created.

1) Are you sure the path exists?
2) Can you try using a path without spaces, i.e. c:\temp\log1.txt

Comment: Hi Abhi, were you running this through SSMS and did you get any errors or was the file simply not created?

Comment: Thanks, either space was creating the issue or i did not have permission for that folder. It worked perfectly when I changed the path to temp. @Gizmo : No the SSMS gave the message "Command(s) completed successfully."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a bath that Sql Server can access. To check if a path is valid, put a database backup in it and try to restore it. If you cannot, then sql server can't access this path.